# Making 3d lines with pycollada

Tags: python, qgis, collada

I am using QGIS and there is a plugin Qgis2threejs that can accept collada files along with the current map layer and produce three.js output. I am not familiar with collada, but I want to use pycollada to build a set of 3d lines that I can import into the plugin.

I am having a lot of trouble understanding how to do this with pycollada, I don't see many tutorials or examples on the internet, the ones I see are mostly for cubes.

I basically want to know how to build the simplest python script that will create lines if I know the x,y,z coordinates of each point and then write them to the file.

Does anyone know of a tutorial that does this, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

[This lineset test](https://github.com/pycollada/pycollada/blob/master/collada/tests/test_lineset.py#L31) in the repo should give you a good example.

You should also read the [Creating A Collada Object](https://pycollada.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating.html) section of the docs.